# I am trying to add large numbers using arrays without using bigint or anything like that. C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to add large numbers using arrays without using bigint or anything like that. I can get my program to add the two arrays. However, I need to take the addition of the arrays and output the correct answer like a regular number. I cannot seem to make an algorithm to take the sum of my arrays and ouptut the answer. Does anybody have any tips or suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

const int DIGITS = 20;

void readNum(int list[], int& length, string input1);
void reverseArray(int arr[], int start, int end);
void sumNum(int list1[], int numOfElementsList1,
    int list2[], int numOfElementsList2);


int main()
{
    // Write your main here
    string input1;
    string input2;
    int list[DIGITS];
    int list2[DIGITS];
    int total[DIGITS];
    int input1Length;
    int input2Length;
    cout << "Please enter your 1st number: " << endl;
    cin >> input1;
    cout << "Please enter your 2nd number: " << endl;
    cin >> input2;
    input1Length = input1.length();
    input2Length = input2.length();
    readNum(list, input1Length, input1);
    readNum(list2, input2Length, input2);
    reverseArray(list, 0, input1Length);
    reverseArray(list2, 0, input2Length);
    sumNum(list, input1Length, list2, input2Length);
   

}
void readNum(int list[], int& length, string input1)
{
  
    int array[DIGITS];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = input1[i] - '0';
        list[i] = array[i];
    }
}
void reverseArray(int arr[], int start, int length)
{
    int end;
    end = length - 1;
    while (start < end)
    {
        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
void sumNum(int list1[], int numOfElementsList1,
    int list2[], int numOfElementsList2)
{
    int length;
    int sum = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    int total[DIGITS];
    if (numOfElementsList1 > numOfElementsList2)
    {
        length = numOfElementsList1;
    }
    else
    {
        length = numOfElementsList2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        sum = list1[i] + list2[i] + carry;
        if (sum >= 10)
        {
            sum = sum % 10;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0;
        }
        total[i] = sum;
        cout << total[i];
    }
        
    

}
```

Comment: *Does anybody have any tips or suggestions?* -- Create a real class instead of having standalone functions.  Then the code would be easier to diagnose.  Second, it is easier to first make both numbers to add the same size, with the number with less digits being backfilled by zeros.  Then addition would become very easy, as you are not dealing with different sized strings of digits.  And note, what if the numbers are both 20 digits, thus could yield a number with 21 digits if there is a carry at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are arrays of characters, you could just use them as-is.  The advantage being... they're just strings, and you can output them as a string just as easily.  Not a new technique, it's called a *binary coded decimal* which in this case is a zoned BCD (where the zone is `0x30` in ASCII, or zone `0xF0` in EBCDIC).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::runtime_error;

static string sumNum(string, string);

int main() {
    string input1;
    string input2;
    cout << "Please enter your 1st number: ";
    cin >> input1;
    cout << "Please enter your 2nd number: ";
    cin >> input2;
    auto sum = sumNum(input1, input2);
    cout << "Sum is: " << sum << "\n";
}

string sumNum(string a, string b) {
    //a = string(a.rbegin(), a.rend());
    //b = string(b.rbegin(), b.rend());
    string sum;

    auto digit = [carry = 0](int value) mutable {
        value += carry;
        if (value > 9) {
            carry = 1;
            value -= 10;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }

        return static_cast<char>(value + '0');
    };

    auto num = [](char c) {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
            throw runtime_error("not a digit");
        }

        return c - '0';
    };

    auto aa = a.rbegin();
    auto bb = b.rbegin();

    while(aa != a.rend() && bb != b.rend()) {
        sum.push_back(digit((num(*aa)) + (num(*bb))));
        ++aa;
        ++bb;
    }

    while (aa != a.rend()) {
        sum.push_back(digit(num(*aa)));
        ++aa;
    }

    while (bb != b.rend()) {
        sum.push_back(digit(num(*bb)));
        ++bb;
    }

    char last = digit(0);
    if (last != '0')
        sum.push_back(last);

    return string(sum.rbegin(), sum.rend());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works. But I have to use an array to do the sum.

Comment: `std::string` uses an array to store the `char`.